# Login to a website with HTTP Basic Authentication from Android app

Tags: java, android, http, authentication

I've already searched for many ways to do this, but i can't find any working way.

I want to login to this site:
http://www.besselgymnasium.de/fileadmin/Vertretung/Vertretungsplan_Schueler/subst_001.htm which uses HTTP Basic Authentication using my android app to read out the source code, but i don't know how i could let my app login automatically.

Could somebody tell me how this can be achieved?

The last thing i tried was:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    quellcode = (TextView) findViewById(com.example.MainActivity.R.id.TextView01);
    geschichte = (TextView) findViewById(com.example.MainActivity.R.id.geschichte);
    datum1 = (TextView) findViewById(com.example.MainActivity.R.id.datum1);
    datum1.setText("25.03.2014");
    readWebpage(quellcode);

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    //getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
private class DownloadWebPageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String credentials = "username" + ":" + "password";
        Base64.encodeToString(credentials.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);





        String response = "";
        for (String url : urls) {
            DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
            httpGet.setHeader("Authorization", "Basic "+credentials);
            try {
                HttpResponse execute = client.execute(httpGet);
                InputStream content = execute.getEntity().getContent();

                BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
                String s = "";
                while ((s = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
                    response += s;
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return response;

    }
    //END OF READING

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        quellcode.setText(result);


    }
}


public void readWebpage(View view) {
    DownloadWebPageTask task = new DownloadWebPageTask();
    task.execute(new String[]{"http://username:password@www.besselgymnasium.de/fileadmin/Vertretung/Vertretungsplan_Schueler/subst_001.htm"});

}
```

}

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To access the web site you have to add the Authorization header.

First you have to concatenate and encode with base64 your credentials:

```
string credentials = username + ":" + password;
string credBase64 = Base64.encodeToString(credentials.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT).replace("\n", "");
```

then you add this header to your httpClient:

```
httpGet.setHeader("Authorization", "Basic "+credBase64);
```

Feel free to ask if you need more help.

Comment: Okay, I added that to my code. 
But now i get the error:
java: no suitable method found for encode(java.lang.String)
    method android.util.Base64.encode(byte[],int,int,int) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    method android.util.Base64.encode(byte[],int) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)

Do you know why?

Comment: As I said I used pseudo code for that part. In Android you can use: `Base64.encodeToString("text".getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT)` or any other base64 library to achieve this

Comment: Okay, i tried it with that code. I updated my code above.
The code compiles and everything but i still can't login and get the source code from the failed authentication.
Any idea why?

Comment: Are you concatenating the colon (:) between your username and password?

Comment: Yes, seen in this line:
String credentials = "username" + ":" + "password";

Comment: Ok... You can do this to check that you are creating your header properly. Open the web page on Google Chrome, open the developer console (press F12), go to the Network tab reload the page and check the Authorization header. make sure it matches with the one you are sending from your App, you can base64.decode it if you want to check the credentials on plain text.

Comment: Okay, i checked that. My base64.encode is the same as the one that i see in the developer console. 
Could it be that i don't send this code correctly?

Comment: If your web server is IIS maybe you should use domain\username as username.

Comment: @user2051194 I've reproduced your issue and successfully logged in using http basic authorization by removing the `\n` on `credBase64`. see updated answer.

Comment: Also you should append the `credBase64` string to the header not `credentials`

Comment: Where did you remove the \n ?
Edit: Ah i just saw it :)

It works now! Thank you sooooooo much! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using SharedPreferences. In this way, you will be able to store the login details for the first time you start the app. Next time onwards, you can read those values.

Follow this tutorial for SharedPreferences:
[Tutorials Point](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_shared_preferences.htm)

Comment: I already have the login details and don't need to set them after the app started. I just want to know how to pass them on to the website and login.

Comment: oh! ok. for that you may probably need to contact the site admin as different sites may have different authentication protocols